# Double mapping through array result in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map function that goes through each task (see the first image) and add task.title into div with id equals to task.deadline.
There are 30/31 divs (depends on month) - every has an id in format ("YYYY-MM-DD") - the same format as task.deadline.
However, every task is doubled (see the second image - there are displayed task.id instead of task.title) for better visibility.
There is a maping function.
I've tried the same with for loop.

```
tasks.map((task) => {
  var taskDay = document.getElementById(task.deadline);
  if(taskDay){
    var newTaskP = document.createElement("p");
    newTaskP.innerHTML = task.taskId;
    taskDay.appendChild(newTaskP);
  }
})
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like ReactJS code at all.  If you're manually manipulating DOM elements in your React component(s) then you're very much doing it wrong and could cause all sorts of problems during re-renders.  You might want to take a step back and re-evaluate how you're using React and make use of JSX in its render functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't really understand your question. I assume that every item inside `tasks` has one `title` and one `deadline`.

You don't have to use `document.getElementById()` or `document.createElement()` in React Js because React Js handles the DOM for you. All you have to do is to return a single `html tag` inside a function in React Js. Also don't forget to put `key` prop with (must be a unique item for every item, usually an `id`) to the parent `html tag`.

So if you want to map the `tasks` and print the `title` inside a `div` element in React Js, you could do this:

```js
tasks.map(task => (
    <div key={task.deadline}>
        <p>{task.title}</p>
    </div>
))
```

or:

```js
tasks.map(task => {
    return(
        <div key={task.deadline}>
            <p>{task.title}</p>
        </div>
    )
})
```